# How do you identify when content in frame has reloaded?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

**Background**

Chromedriver currently has a [bug (3361)](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3361) that breaks some of my existing test functionality. The core bug makes looking at the content in frames which are being loaded nearly impossible. The problem started in chromedriver 77 (see [3164](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3164)) , but as of 80 they still don't have any insight as to how they are going to fix it.

**My test scenario:**

Click a button that is 2 frames deep (outer frame, then inner frame) which causes the inner frame to reload the page.  Depending on the button sometimes the page changes, other times it simply reloads the same page.

Inspired from [this post](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/how-to-get-selenium-to-wait-for-page-load-after-a-click.html) I wrote a context_manager method to wait for the inner page to reload.

```py
    ############################################################################
    def switchToFrameContent(self, wait: typeWait):
        """
        moves to the content frame if not already on it.
        """
        if self._onFrame(xcn.EcBase.frame.content.Frame()):
            return
        self.resetFrame()
        self._switchToTop(wait)
        self._switchToContent(wait, VERBOSE)
        return
    
    @contextmanager
    @UnexpectedAlertExceptionDecorator
    def waitForContentPageLoad(self, wait: typeWait):
        """:param wait: default is wait"""
        logger.verbose("waiting for Content page to load")
        self.switchToFrameContent()
        old_page = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name("html")
        yield
        self.switchToFrameContent()
        # a logging wrapper for wait.until(ec)
        self.wait_until(staleness_of(old_page), "page became stale!!!", wait)
```

Which would be used like so:

```py
with self.waitForContentPageLoad():
    # looks for the element via wrapper around expected_condition.element_to_be_clickable then calls element.click()
    self.clickbutton(some_ec, msg=f"Could not find '{some_ec}' menu item", wait=self.wait)
```

Chromedriver bug [3361](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3361) breaks this functionality so that when we try to wait for the `staleness_of(old_page)` the exception `NoSuchWindowException` is thrown.

They even offer a basic suggestion on how to deal with it:

> *In the meantime, please add some delay after clicking on the button, before switching to the iframe. Or catch the exception and try again.*

I go out of my way to avoid static waits; the problem being knowing exactly how long to wait. So ideally I would like to solve the problem without static waits. **I'm having a hard time coming up with an idea on how to identify when a page in a frame has reloaded.**

**edit**

I believe I misunderstood the bug. `staleness_of(old_page)` fails because it is checking against a destroyed context.  IN OTHER WORDS: wait a second for the new frame to load then try checking to see if the element is stale.

This makes me wonder if possible to identify when a frame has gone stale. Something like:

```py
wait.until(staleness_of(frame))
wait.until(staleness_of(old_page))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this will help the java folks -- but in python selenium the `WebDriverWait` class has an argument for `ignored_exceptions`. Passing in `NoSuchWindowException` before using `wait.until()` appears to bypass this bug.

I'm still cautious about suggesting it's use everywhere, but as far as I can tell that exception is only raised in the case where the frame context doesn't exist yet (i.e. bug [3361](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3361)) or while trying to navigate to an actual window that doesn't exist.  If I'm right, it should mean that telling WebDriverWait to ignore `NoSuchWindowException` should work great.

This is only useful if you're using `expected_conditions` to find elements - *(which I would almost exclusively recommend)*